# How to close a div permanently using jQuery

Tags: jquery, stateful

I have 5 pages and I am including a banner in the 1st page, if the user closes the banner in 1st page then the banner should not appear in the other pages too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".alert-banner-hide").on("click", function(){
            $("#alert-banner-container").hide();
      });

});
```

Could you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to set something like a cookie or sessionStorage value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage` Object to have something stateful :

### For On-close Banner event :

```
  $(".alert-banner-hide").on("click", function(){
        $("#alert-banner-container").hide();
        sessionStorage.setItem("banner-closed","yes"); //add this instruction
  });
```

And

### on Pages load / Document ready :

```
  // Copy/Paste the whole code below & don't worry 
  $(function(){
         if (sessionStorage.getItem('banner-closed')==="yes"){
              //trigger close banner
             $("#alert-banner-container").hide();
         }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Its working fine,
Could you please share any url to learn JavaScript and jQuery for beginner.

Comment: @San : "JS essential Training Simon Allardice" put it in  google & enjoy.. Good training !

Comment: Need a clarification,
When I right click and open in new tab, still the banner is appearing.

In same tab its working fine.